# Pylint Install on Windows

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt, pylint, python-3.9

I am attempting to install pylint and I receive the following errors. I am pretty sure that pip is not working for me so I tried adding the script paths to the system variable path. After doing so it still didn't work. I also cant check what version of pip i have in the command prompt.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\tre\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\users\tre\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Tre\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

[image]

Any Tips?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots - they create an accessibility problem, and they cannot be indexed by search engines. Instead, copy&paste the error message as text.

Comment: what do you see running `pip -V` ?

Comment: C:\Users\Tre\Python\Python39\Scripts>pip -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\tre\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\tre\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Tre\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Comment: looks like you don't have `pip` installed

Comment: When I go to my scripts folder pip, pip3.9, and pip3 are there. Is that something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, there seems to be a problem with your pip installation.
Try installing pip first. You can do it as follows:
1 Open cmd and run the following command
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

2. In the same directory run:
python get-pip.py


I think this should resolve your issue. If not, the easiest solution, re-install python!! XD

Comment: I cant believe it was something so simple. Thank you

Comment: You can use `python -m ensurepip` too